# Why when clicking on a guilayout.button to color the text of the button from red to green it's taking a lot of time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Linq;

public class ScriptsManager : EditorWindow
{
    static Vector2 scrollPos;
    List<GUIStyle> styles = new List<GUIStyle>();

    [MenuItem("Tools/Scripts")]
    static void Scripts()
    {
        EditorWindow.GetWindow<ScriptsManager>();
        GetWindow<ScriptsManager>().minSize = new Vector2(900, 500);
        GetWindow<ScriptsManager>().maxSize = new Vector2(900, 500);
        GetWindow<ScriptsManager>().maximized = false;
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        string[] assetPaths = AssetDatabase.GetAllAssetPaths();

        if (styles.Count() < assetPaths.Length)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < assetPaths.Length; y++)
            {
                styles.Add(new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.button));
                styles[y].normal.textColor = Color.red;
                styles[y].fontSize = 18;
            }
        }

        EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
        scrollPos =
            EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Width(900), GUILayout.Height(500));

        for (int i = 0; i < assetPaths.Length; i++)
        {
            if (assetPaths[i].Contains(".cs"))
            {
                var x = assetPaths[i].LastIndexOf("/");
                var t = assetPaths[i].Substring(x + 1);

                if (GUILayout.Button(t, styles[i], GUILayout.Width(1000), GUILayout.Height(50)))
                {
                    Event.current.type = EventType.Repaint;

                    if (GUILayoutUtility.GetLastRect().Contains(Event.current.mousePosition))
                    {
                        OnMouseOver(i, assetPaths[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
        EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
    }

    private void OnMouseOver(int buttinIndex, string file)
    {
        styles[buttinIndex].normal.textColor = Color.green;
    }
}
```

Only if I'm doing this line:

```
Event.current.type = EventType.Repaint;
```

It will color the current button I clicked on to green.
The problem is when I click on the first one or two buttons it's changing the color first to green but then then ext buttons I click on it's taking longer and longer then in some cases it's taking some seconds even almost 10 seconds to change the color to green.

If I will remove the line it will work fast but without coloring the buttons text to green.

Comment: There is an overflow at OnGUI check here >>>>>>  if (styles.Count() < assetPaths.Length)

Comment: @RonTang Right, But then how do I color the buttons text first time in red ? It must be inside the OnGUI. I will tell you what is my main goal. To make that I will be able to click on each single button and that button text will change from red to green and also to use a scrollbar up down to see all the buttons. I can't figure out for days now how to use the scrollbar and the buttons click event/s to change the colors.

Comment: Could you use a bool var to represent first time?Like if(!init){ init();init =true;} Sorry,I don't understand well about your question.